# Business Open/Closed text on page according to time

Tags: javascript, html

I must have tried a 100 variations of this code and can't seem to get it right.  I feel like I'm walking further off the playing field.

I want to display a message on our pages that show whether our business is open or closed depending on time and/or day.

Here is my current code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var today = new Date()
var open = ("We're open today from 9am - 5pm</span>");
var closed = ("We're closed and will open again tomorrow 9am - 6pm</span>");
if (today == 0) display.innerHTML = 'closed';
if (today.getHours() >= 9 && today.getHours() < 18) {
    display.innerHTML = 'open';
} else {
    display.innerHTML = 'closed';
}
</script>
```

and the HTML I'm currently using.

```
<div><span id="display"></span></div>
```

Comment: Missing semicolon after `new Date()`. check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whcug6gj/). Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: @alex: getUTCHours()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/undLy2mp/1/)):

```
var today = new Date(),
    open = "We're open today from 9am - 5pm",
    closed = "We're closed and will open again tomorrow 9am - 6pm",
    display = document.getElementById('display');

if (today.getHours() >= 9 && today.getHours() < 18) {
    display.innerHTML = open;
} else {
    display.innerHTML = closed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="display"></div>
```

I assume your problem was that it was displaying "open" or "closed" in the `div`, when it should be displaying either "We're open today from 9am - 5pm" or "We're closed and will open again tomorrow 9am - 6pm". The issue was that you were referencing the variables `open` and `closed` as strings.

Comment: It might not be a likely case, yet I recommend to use getUTCHours() for such stuff.

Comment: @Lain, for sure, definitely a good point (to account for differences in time zones, etc.)