# Display Open/Close for Business Hours using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to make "open" display between 11:00 am to 8:30 pm (20:30) using only pure javascript for a local business. I can get it to work for 11:00 am to 8 pm (20:00) but I can't figure out how to get it to work for 20:30.

```
const paragraph = document.querySelector("#openClose");
let d = new Date();
let day = d.getDay();
let hours = d.getHours();
let minutes = d.getMinutes();

if (day === 5 && hours >= 11 && hours < 20) {
    openClose.textContent = "Open."
} else { 
    openClose.textContent = "Closed." 
}

//I tried, among other things:

if(day === 5 && hours >= 11 && hours < 20 && minutes < 30) {…
```

I read this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766336/business-open-closed-text-on-page-according-to-time) article, but missed something, it didn't help me.

Comment: Just to point out that the store's timezone and the user's timezone might not be the same.  This code is all using the user's timezone.

Comment: James, I'm going to look at the date methods and see if there is one that will set it to the timezone of the business. I hope there is. I'm sorry if I'm a bother in any way, I've been doing my best to teach myself html, css, and javascript using free online tutorials. Thank You for pointing that out.

Comment: Question:  

How do I account for the timedifference and set it to display open and close according to the business' timezone?

To James or anyone, 
I've been trying to figure out how to make open and close show according to the business' timezone and not the users as per what James notified me of.
I found and read about getTimeZoneOffset but I don't know this can be used to account for the timezone difference between the user and business.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you're asking: you want it to work from 11 to 20 regardless of minutes, and then also work for 20 up to 30 minutes past. So that's two partitions of the hours, and one of the minutes, meaning you'll need two different terms in your condition.

```
if ((hours >= 11 && hours < 20) || (hours === 20 && minutes < 30)) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me IceMetalPunk. You made it very clear and easy to understand. I greatly appreciate that. : )

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
if(day === 5 && hours >= 11 && // this always matters
          (
               hours < 20 ||  // if it's less than 20 minutes don't matter
               (hours === 20 && minutes < 30) // if it's 20 then minutes matter
          )
    )
```

As per the day

> The getDay() method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date.
>
> Note: Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.

Comment: Thank You Athanasios Kataras for reminding me how the days are numbered in JS, and for taking the code example a step further.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statement to:

```
if (day === 5 && ((hours >= 11 && hours < 20) || (hours === 20 && minutes < 30)))
```

Comment: whoops, two people beat me to this.

Comment: Thank you jimboweb for showing me another way to write the code.